# Getting empty form in Django with MetaForm

Tags: python, django, forms

I have this as template account_form.html

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

My model.py

```
class Account(models.Model):
        person_name     = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        account_number  = models.IntegerField()
        creation_date   = models.DateField()
```

My View is

```
def account_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = AccountForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
                # ...
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = AccountForm() # An unbound form

    return render_to_response('account_form.html', {
            'form': form,
    })
```

The problem is when i load the page i only get the submit button nothing else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to actually create your form:

Should read something like this:

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from yourapp.models import Account

class AccountForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
```

This will give you all fields from Account.

HTH

Comment: thans buddy , actually i wrote this AccountForm(froms.Form) instead of AccountForm(ModelForm): , i dont' know why it didn't worked

Comment: that depends on what you're trying to do. If you like to create a from which is directly bound to your Model, use Modelform otherwise you can create every form with you method.
have a look in the Django docs, about Modelforms: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/